# Can not enable Livepatch service on 22.04

Tags: canonical-livepatch, 22.04

I just did a clean install of 22.04 today.  When trying to enable live patch I see I see the following message.  I tried uninstall and reinstalling the livepatch app/snap but that didn't resolve the issue.  Any ideas how I might resolve this?[image: livepatch enable error]

Comment: As of today (look the date of the post) I was able to enable the service finally after trying for a month. So it should work now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you to try enableing it from [Ubuntu Advantages](https://ubuntu.com/advantage) page

If needed, a detailed guide could be found [here in this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enable-the-livepatch-service#1-overview)

Also, if the above configurations are completed already, just run below commands in terminal as [defined here](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/client/enabling) to enable the live patch

```
# Attach your personal or enterprise subscription from ubuntu.com/advantage
$ sudo ua attach [TOKEN]

# Explicitly enable livepatch
$ sudo ua enable livepatch
```

Comment: the command line worked for me. so many things do not work properly in 22.04....

Comment: the `pro status` command gives more information than the ui concerning the source of the issues with livepatch