# Unable to enable livepatch - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04

I cannot enable the livepatch on my computer, I was able to attach the machine by running sudo ua attach [TOKEN] but when I run sudo canonical-livepatch enable [token], it throws this error:

failed to register client: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/94e4d8c2ed4a412a944112037a19b472" failed

but my Ubuntu Advantage subscription is active under free personal token and it also show one machine is attached under the subscription. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not enable Livepatch service on 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403568/can-not-enable-livepatch-service-on-22-04)

Comment: I have followed these steps already, it did not work.